# Using a Defined Name in a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of cells with values:

A1,B3,C5,D7,E11,F13,G17,H19,I23

I have a formula to select, at random, the value stored in one of these cells:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,9),A1,B3,C5,D7,E11,F13,G17,H19,I23)
```

The formula works fine.  Now I have assigned a *Defined Name* to this set of cells - **MyPicks**
How can I change the formula to use the Defined Name rather than the hard-coded list ??

**EDIT#1:**

I tried to make the group of cell **contiguous** by using **A1,A2,A3** and sure enough:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),A1,A2,A3)
```

but `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),contig)`

fails the same way with **contig** defined as the *Name* of cells **A1,A2,A3**:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use the Defined Name in the formula; `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,9), MyPicks)`?

Comment: @CharlieRB  I get **#VALUE!**

Comment: Interesting, you can't even `=index(name,number)` unless the named range is contiguous.

Comment: @Raystafarian ..............I can't even get *INDIRECT()* to work with *CHOOSE()*

Comment: @Raystafarian  Even a contiguous set of cells does not work, see my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: If you have contiguous just use something like `=INDEX(named2,,RANDBETWEEN(1,5))` adjusting for a vertical range rather than horizontal

Comment: @Raystafarian ........THANK You ...........THANK YOU .......THANK YOU.

Comment: The reason `CHOOSE` isn't working is because it's seeing the named range as a single value instead of a collection of cells each having their own value. If you use `=CHOOSE(1,MyPicks)` then it works fine - although it only returns the value from the first cell - but `=CHOOSE(2,MyPicks)` fails because there isn't a second value for `CHOOSE` to return.

Comment: Off topic a little.....but assuming named2 is a contiguous vector it can be either vertical or horizontal and the same function works for either - `INDEX(named2,RANDBETWEEN(1,5))` - When the range is a vector (single column or row) you only need one argument to define the position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions **will** accept a discontiguous range as an argument, e.g. `FREQUENCY`, `RANK`, `SMALL`, `LARGE`.

In this case you could use one of those latter two, e.g.

`=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,9))`

If the size of `MyPicks` might be variable, or some cells may not be populated you could make the `RANDBETWEEN` part depend on the number of values in `MyPicks`, i.e.

`=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT(MyPicks)))`

Note: the functions listed will accept a named discontiguous range as above.....or you can use the specific cells directly as a **union** - cell references separated by commas and bracketed together, e.g.

`=SMALL((A1,B3,C5,D7,E11,F13,G17,H19,I23),RANDBETWEEN(1,9))`

Comment: Thanks!.........this exactly achieves my goal without having to fight with *CHOOSE()*