# Counting the Cells in a Named Range without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a disjoint set of 9 cells:  *A1,B3,C5,D7,E11,F13,G17,H19,I23*.  I have assigned a *Name* to these cells:  *MyPicks*
I have a simple formula to pick the value in one of these cells at random:

```
=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,9))
```

the formula works:

[image]

However each time I change the number of cells in the *Named Range*, I must go back and change the **9** in the formula!  So I decided to "fix" the formula:

**First try:**

```
=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(MyPicks)))
```

This appeared to work.  However *COUNTA()* only counts cells with values or Nulls.  It ignores totally empty cells.  So...........

**Second try:**

```
=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(MyPicks)+COUNTBLANK(MyPicks)))
```

Sadly, this produces a #VALUE! error because *COUNTBLANK()* does not work on disjoint ranges.  So............

**Third try:**

I created a small VBA UDF:

```
Public Function nCount(r As Range) As Long
    nCount = r.Count
End Function
```

Using this UDF solved the problem.  I then discovered my customer was macrophobic and the solution was instantly rejected.

Is it possible to count the total number of cells in a *Named Range* without VBA ??

Comment: +1 Excellent question. We should get meta to point to this as an example of what to include so that your data setup, problem, and previous attempts are all clearly understood.

Comment: The question I was thinking of was actually [yours](http://superuser.com/questions/887843/using-a-defined-name-in-a-formula/888031). Nevermind

Comment: Why count the number of **cells**? If you do that then the `SMALL` function can return an error because `RANDBETWEEN` can return a number larger than the count of numbers in MyPicks

Comment: @barryhoudini  **OUCH** ..................you are correct!! .............I will have to pick from a table of addresses of the *Named Range* ................can you suggest another approach ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean - text values won't work in this context because SMALL only deals with numbers. Do you want to pick random text values from a discontiguous range? That might be tricky......

Comment: @barryhoudini ...........I decided to create a short table of the *addresses* of the elements of the *Named Range*.  This table will have to be managed manually............but at least it will facilitate picking at random from a disjoint set of numbers, text, and empties..... **THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR UNCOVERING THE BUG!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this little beauty:

```
=SUM(FREQUENCY(MyPicks,MyPicks))
```

Therefore, your whole formula would be:

```
=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM(FREQUENCY(MyPicks,MyPicks))))
```

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out by barry houdini, the `SMALL` function will only return numeric values. In that case, the `SUM(FREQUENCY())` solution is overkill. Instead, simply use

```
=SMALL(MyPicks,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT(MyPicks)))
```

Comment: Thanks!.................it saddens me that I can only up-vote this once!

Comment: Does this really do what you asked? Doesn't `=SUM(FREQUENCY(MyPicks,MyPicks))` just give a count of numbers in MyPicks - you can get the same result using `=COUNT(MyPicks)`

Comment: @barryhoudini `COUNT` only counts numbers which, given the exact example, would meet OP's needs. My solution works for numbers or text.

Comment: From Excel Help: FREQUENCY ignores blanks cells and text.....

Answer (score 1):

If each of the disjoint ranges is comprised of a single cell, the following formula will return the number of cells in the range, no matter what the content, or even if they are blank, which I think is what you want:

```
=LEN(CELL("address",MyPicks))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",MyPicks),",",""))+1
```

Comment: This works great for ranges in which no two cells share a common border.  Thanks ..................having empty cells ruins the approach of using *COUTNA()*  which is unfortunate since *COUNTA()* works whether the range is disjoint or "joint".

Comment: It might be possible to do something with "joint" cells, but I think it will be easier to cure your customer of his macrophobia :-)

Comment: ..........................Amen!